# cordova plugman - plugin version management

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, plugman

**enviroment versions:**

- cordova: 7.1.0
- plugman: 1.5.1

I have Installed `plugman`and installed few plugins using it for iOS and Android platforms. I have noticed that the plugins i have installed with `plugman` are not represented in `config.xml`.

Now, in each platform library, There is a path, for example:
`platforms/android/cordova/plugins` which contains a `fetch.json` file, with the plugins i have installed with `plugman`  which looks like that:

```
{
  "cordova-plugin-device": {
    "source": {
      "type": "registry",
      "id": "cordova-plugin-device"
    },
    "is_top_level": true,
    "variables": {}
  }
}
```

My questions are:

- Should I commit this file to the git repository of the project?
- Am i losing version management of plugins installed through `plugman` ?